# Can I get an Example of a Snowflake Stored Procedure that takes in StartDate and ReturnDate then executes 2 Select statements and returns a table()?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can I get an Example of a Snowflake Stored Procedure that takes in StartDate and ReturnDate then executes 2 Select statements and returns a table()?  It needs to be a WORKING example.  Just Table1 and Table2 for table names, etc.  I am just looking for a good example syntax wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return a table, you must use a SQL Script stored procedure. I'm not sure what you want the second select to do, so here's a sample with a single select. Are you looking for the second one to key off of something it finds after running the first statement?

```
create or replace procedure test (start_date date, end_date date)
returns table()
language sql
as
$$

declare
  res resultset default (
    select  *
    from    "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."ORDERS" 
    where   O_ORDERDATE >= :start_date
        and O_ORDERDATE <= :end_date
   );
begin
  return table(res);
end;

$$;

call test('1994-01-01', '1994-01-02');
```